# How can i disable ssl verification on ranger to elastic for audit?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-ranger

I have a elastic cluster with secure.

and I want to audit my apache ranger logs (hdfs) to elastic cluster.

How can i disable **ssl verification**?

I try this and it s not working.

```
<property>
  <name>xasecure.audit.elasticsearch.ssl.verify</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant find any solution to disable sal verification

I add my crt to keytool like below

```
keytool -import -alias alias -file cert_file.crt -keypass keypass -keystore yourkeystore.jks -storepass changeme
```